# Setting jetty 8 with eclipse for working with servlets

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

I'm trying to do super simple "Hello World" Servlet with Jetty working with eclipse.

I have a Jetty Server adapter which is working, but when I try to start on my server I get the following erros;

The servlet code:

```
package My;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class My_Servlet
 */
@WebServlet("/My_Servlet")
public class My_Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public My_Servlet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().println("<html><body><h1>My Servlet</h1></body></html>");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
                HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
                HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

The error I get:

```
Error 404 - Not Found.
No context on this server matched or handled this request.
Contexts known to this server are:

    /My_WS ---> o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/My_WS,file:/home/user/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/My_WS/},/home/user/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/My_WS [failed]
```

That what I see on localhost:8080.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Guy

**EDIT**

I've noticed that I miss classVisitor (which part of Spring framework), and It's becoming to much of an hassle in order to support my simple program. I might switch to tomcat or just use embbeded jetty

Comment: Shouldn't you use URL to your servlet instead of localhost root?

Comment: I did, but It didn't work

Comment: did you try http://localhost:8080/My_Servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, I work with Jetty and NetBeans, and I don't use NetBeans to run the jetty  server. Instead I run it on the command-line using `mvn jetty:run`.

I think your problem is that you are not specifying the servlet to handle requests in your **web.xml** file. The Java code is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: If you want to debug, you run `mvnDebug jetty:run` and attach a debugger in your IDE. Not sure about Eclipse, but it's easy to attach a debugger in NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

Your webapp at the context `http://localhost:8080/My_WS/`

Your Servlet is at `http://localhost:8080/My_WS/My_Servlet`

The error you are seeing is from you hitting `http://localhost:8080/` which isn't setup to do anything with your simple scenario.